# Ansible: Add an additional field to a set of values already defined in hosts.yaml

Tags: ansible

I have the following piece of code inside the inventory hosts.yaml:

```
---
all:
  hosts:
    myhost:
      default_ok:
        a:
          x: default
          y: default
        b: default
        c: default
      patch_ok:
        a:
          y: patch
          z: patch
        b: patch
      default_nok:
      - a:
        - x
        - y
        c: default_c_nok
      - a:
        - x
        - y
        c: default2_c_nok
      patch_nok:
        b: patch_b_nok
```

and the following piece of code for the Playbook:

```
- name: test OK
  set_fact:
    default_ok: '{{ default_ok | combine(patch_ok, recursive=true) }}'
  tags: [init]

- name: debug test OK
  ansible.builtin.debug:
  loop: '{{ [default_ok] }}'
  tags: [init]

- name: test NOK
  set_fact:
    default_nok: '{{ default_nok | combine(patch_nok, recursive=true) }}'
  loop: '{{ default_nok }}'
  tags: [init]

- name: debug test NOK
  ansible.builtin.debug:
  loop: '{{ [default_nok] }}'
  tags: [init]
```

For the `default_ok` all looks good:

```
  default_ok:
    a:
      x: default
      y: patch
      z: patch
    b: patch
    c: default
```

Debug Logs for the **good** case:

```
TASK [sandbox : test OK] *********************************************************
ok: [myhost] => (item={'c': 'default', 'a': {'x': 'default', 'y': 'default'}, 'b': 'default'})

TASK [sandbox : debug test OK] ***************************************************
ok: [myhost] => (item={'c': 'default', 'a': {'y': 'patch', 'x': 'default', 'z': 'patch'}, 'b': 'patch'}) => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
```

For the `default_nok` example **we should see** in debug at the end the following:

```
  default_nok:
  - a:
    - x
    - y
    b: patch_b_nok
    c: default_c_nok
  - a:
    - x
    - y
    b: patch_b_nok
    c: default2_c_nok
```

BUT the debug just show the adjustment of one:

```
TASK [sandbox : test NOK] *********************************************************
ok: [myhost] => (item={'c': 'default_c_nok', 'a': ['x', 'y']})
ok: [myhost] => (item={'c': 'default2_c_nok', 'a': ['x', 'y']})

TASK [sandbox : debug test NOK] ***************************************************
ok: [myhost] => (item={'c': 'default2_c_nok', 'b': 'patch_b_nok', 'a': ['x', 'y']}) => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: Use Ansible `combine` filter. See, https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries

Comment: When you use that example, yes it works. But with my data above it is not. As the structure is different. Check the member and then the List of user below.
Did not get it work with the example above. Ansible Examples on docs.ansible.com are working. Any code snipped which I could try?

Comment: This is all very confusing. `service_a` is a host in your inventory. As such, you cannot really use this name as a var directly. Meanwile `hostvars['service_a']` exists and contains a dictionary of all vars gathered or declared for that host. You are talking about a list but you show an example of a dict where one element is a list containing a single element being a dict itself. What is the exact variable you want to loop over ? Please show a real debug example of your loop task with a sample run. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited/rephrased the Question again and put code examples here to reproduce.
If there's still any question please let me know. Hope the issue is now more clear. Thanks.